# Publish a page from our domain in to another domain, without showing the the URL of our server

Tags: php, javascript, saas

I am developing a SaaS based application in PHP , in which my clients (web site owners ) can create and customize some contact forms. Then I would like to publish that page to my client web site with out showing the url ( I mean it needs to seem like the page from my clients domain ). We can see the same situations in surey monkey and other online chat applications . Please help me to solve this .

Thanks in advance,

Sunil

Comment: tell the client to load content from your server, either by http with cURL or whatever else

Comment: The easiest way is to embed your forms within a iframe that your clients should be build in their websites.

Comment: @HernanVelasquez: embedding with iframe will show the url of his server

Comment: @Sunil Kumar P: is your client website coded in php?

Comment: I believe you could do iframe as others suggested, or maybe submit info with jquery or javascript.

Comment: Thanks for your time , It is a SaaS based app, so the client may use PHP, .net etc etc. Can I use frame set tag to access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 Solutions:

**iframe** - Downside is, many people don't like them.  Some people have security issues with it.  Other than that, they are just fine.

**External Javascript file** - Include it in your header, have it populate the page with specific content.  Works like a charm and you can even use remote files: `<script src="http://external.com/form.php" type="text/javascript"></script>`.  Downside, possible conflicts in the page if user wants to include own content on the page.  Personally I prefer this method and use it in syncing a website menu across multiple servers (some apache, some tomcat).

**JSONP** - Much like the external Javascript file, load up the external page via a JSONP request.  Downside, a lot of configuration, more than just including the one line above.

**curl** - Great tool, no way for anyone to realize the content is from another side.  Requires backend configuration and more than just plain HTML.  More coding.  More professional.

Comment: Thanks for your time , Can I use frame set tag to do this ?

Comment: Can we access the php file as <script src="http://external.com/form.php" type="text/javascript"></script> ?

Comment: You can do frame set.  you can access php... however the php must have javascript in it.

Comment: Thanks very much . Now I have 2 solutions frameset and script, which is better ? I would like to do the following , 1) Any web site owner can create contact forms in my web app. then I would like to give him a small code snipt. 2) Then he will just paste this code to his web site source. 3) Then when his site loads , I would like to show a small icon their, when any of his visitor clicks in that icon , I would like to show the contact form ,(he designed from my web app) in his web site . Then after submitting the form , I would like to get the details to my server.  Thanks in advance

Comment: Either way, its just preference.  Frames have a little more too them usually, but can be customized.  Scripts are simple to paste, but they maybe be harder to customize.  Frames, output is html, while script is javascript.